# Calling fdupes from AppleScript

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I want to run `fdupes . -dN` on the `~/Desktop/md` directory from an AppleScript.

```
do shell script "/bin/bash fdupes ~/Desktop/wd ." with administrator privileges
```

I got this error

> error "/bin/bash: fdupes: No such file or directory" number 127

But I can issue this commands on the terminal just fine.
[image]

I installed the command line from terminal using `brew install fdupes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do shell script` statement:

- executes the command passed with `sh`, which is `bash` run in POSIX compatibility mode.
- uses a stripped-down version of the `$PATH` variable, which on my OSX 10.10.3 system, amounts to: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
- runs the command in the *root* directory, `/`.

Thus:

- no need to invoke `bash` explicitly (assuming you're not using features not available in POSIX compatibility mode, such as `<(...)` (process substitution)).
- you must invoke non-preinstalled utilities with a *full* path (or append dirs. such as `/usr/local/bin` to the `$PATH` variable as part of the command).

Assuming that `fdupes` is in `/usr/local/bin` (adjust accordingly):

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/fdupes ~/Desktop/wd ." with administrator privileges
```

But note that **`.` will refer to `/` by default** - prepend a `cd` command as needed.

A note re your original command (since modified): you need to use `&&`, not `&` to join the commands - the latter launches the preceding command in the *background*.

Comment: `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/fdupes fdupes ~/Desktop/wd ."` execute the command thanks